# Piecewise function

Tags: piecewise

I have the differential equation

$$
\omega'(t)= \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{J_t}\left(\frac{B}{2}(F_l-F_r)-B_l\omega\right) & \text{if turning=true}\\
                    0   &     \text{if turning=false}
\end{cases}
$$

and I want to solve it.
I have written

```
w[t_] = Piecewise[{{1/J(B/2(F1(t)-F2(t))-Bw(t)), turning=1}, {0, turning=0}]
D[w[t], t]
```

but I think it's not correct. Could anyone help me please???

Comment: You are missing a right parentheses in the definition of `w`. Functions must always use square brackets around the arguments, e.g., `F1[t]` Also, the conditions must use `Equal` ( `==` ) rather than `Set` ( `=` ).

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on what you are doing with the differential equation. Are you using `DSolve` or `NDSolve`?

```
ω'[t] == 1/Jt*(B/2*(Fl[t] - Fr[t]) - Bl*ω[t]) * Boole[turning[t]]
```

could be a way of specifying this differential equation.

Once you have definitions for $J_t$, $F_l(t)$, $F_r(t)$, $B_l$, $\text{turning}(t)$, and an initial value for $\omega(t)$, you can solve this differential equation with `DSolve` or `NDSolve`: something like

```
NDSolve[{ω'[t] == 1/Jt*(B/2*(Fl[t] - Fr[t]) - Bl*ω[t]) * Boole[turning[t]],
         ω[t0] == ω0}, ω[t], {t, t0, t1}]
```

Comment: This is the equation I'm talking about. Thank you
https://ibb.co/ch8cv05